# How to resolve "Preload key requests" performance problem in WordPress Site?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on WordPress Site development and having an issue in performance and site load, "Preload key requests" it takes almost "0.81s", here is the screenshot

[image]
I'm getting following warning from google for lower performance::

> Preload key requests 0.81 s
>
> Consider using  to prioritize fetching resources that are currently requested later in page load.

Google provided a reference link:: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/preload?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=unknown

what should I do to resolve this.please advice? i want to make batter performance for my site.

Answer (score 0):

I used the preload tag below in my header and it works!

```
<link rel=”preload” href="Font URL Showing in PageSpeed "  as=”font” crossorigin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for the solution for very long, and finally found an answer for solving the "preload key request" issue for loading the page faster.

```
<link rel="preload" href="URL showing in PageSpeed Test"  as="font" crossorigin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix preload key requests issue by adding preload link tags in your HTML

```
<link rel="preload" href="Resource URL from page speed"  as="font" type="font type" crossorigin>
```

It is very easy to add  tag in html source. You can either modify your  section within your theme file or using a plugin

[Step by step guide on how to fix reload key requests in wordpress.](http://thepositivepost.com/how-to-fix-preload-key-requests-with-fonts-in-wordpress/)